# Jquery Validation Not working throwing error $.validation is undefinedj

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

jQuery validation is working fine on my machine, when i pushed it to test server it won't it's throwing some errors which is kind of surprising.

These are the errors I am getting:

> $.validator is null or not an object...

I've never gotten this error before and it throwing an error when I declared a variable like `var isValid`.

I don't know what to do. I am doing the custom validation methods not in the `document.ready()`. Does this cause this error? I wonder because all jquery validations are passing and hitting the server side validations.

Comment: Are you sure the paths to jQuery and the Validate plugin are correct ? Providing a link to the problem page would be helpful.

Comment: I just found it...there is mismatching of version for validation plug in and jquery base file..i don't know how it is working on my machine..i don't know..I just changed my jquery file to 1.4.2 and validation plug in to latest one..and its working perfect...thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it...there is mismatching of version for validation plug in and jquery base file..i don't know how it is working on my machine..i don't know..I just changed my jquery file to 1.4.2 and validation plug in to latest one..and its working perfect...thanks for your reply.. –

Answer (score 0):

Almost always this type of `$.<insert-function-here>` is a path or typo error, jQuery cannot find the function.  Check your includes and script for typos and verify the paths are correct.

Comment: I just found it...there is mismatching of version for validation plug in and jquery base file..i don't know how it is working on my machine..i don't know..I just changed my jquery file to 1.4.2 and validation plug in to latest one..and its working perfect...thanks for your reply..